# Usar IDENTITY en una variable para capturar el UserID y con el insertar a otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-express

dejare que mi código hable por mi

```
            USE [FitnessApp]
            GO
            /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[NewUser]    Script Date: 06/01/2021 17:07:26 ******/
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO
            ALTER proc [dbo].[NewUser]


            @LoginName nvarchar(100),
            @FirstName nvarchar(100),
            @LastName nvarchar(100),
            @SexIdent bit,
            @SomatotypeIdent int,
            @age int,
            @Height float,
            @Weight float

            as

            insert into Users values (@LoginName,@FirstName,@LastName,@SexIdent,@SomatotypeIdent,@age, GetDate())



            insert into UserHeight values (@@IDENTITY,@Height, GetDate())

            insert into UserWeight values (@@IDENTITY,@Weight, GetDate())
```

El problema es que al ejecutar este procedimiento no me toma el valor @@IDENTITY ni @UserID me dijeron que lo usara de esa forma pero creo que no capte bien el uso

Comment: ¿Qué hace `mysql` como etiqueta?

Comment: disculpa, fue un error ya lo corrijo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente necesitas "capturar" el valor del `@@IDENTITY` en una variable y luego usarlo.

```
DECLARE @ID INT

insert into Users values (@LoginName,@FirstName,@LastName,@SexIdent,@SomatotypeIdent,@age, GetDate())

SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY

insert into UserHeight values (@ID, @Height, GetDate())
insert into UserWeight values (@ID, @Weight, GetDate())
```

Unos comentarios extras:

- Como buena práctica, siempre escribe los nombres de columnas en el `insert`, es decir `insert into table (col1, col2) values( ... )`, sino, el día que modifiques la estructura de la tabla el código actual fallará.
- En algunos escenarios, es más conveniente usar `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` por sobre `@@IDENTITY` ([Ver](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/sql-server-cuales-son-las-diferencias-entre-at-at-identity-y-scope-identity.aspx#:%7E:text=Aunque%20puedan%20parecer%20iguales%2C%20no,(de%20ah%C3%AD%20su%20nombre).))
- Por último este es un claro escenario para usar [transacciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Como uso el scope_identity para capturar el id?

Comment: `SELECT @ID  = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Lo hice como dijiste pero me dice aun que ID y el identity(lo hice colocando ambos en la inserccion y nada)estan vacios aunque si se crea el usuario

Comment: Y `Users` tiene una columna `IDENTITY`?

Comment: No amigo, identity es la variable para la columna userID

Comment: Es lo que intente explicarte con mi respuesta. El @@IDENTITY es una variable interna de SQL Server que retorna el ultimo valor de IDENTITY insertado en una tabla , lo capturas en una variable justo después del INSERT, esa variable luego la usas para insertar en las otras tablas, esa es la idea. ¿Que cosas no te funcionan o no entiendes?

Comment: Como se dijo anteriormente con el SELECT @ID  = SCOPE_IDENTITY() deberia de funcionarte sin problemas, siempre y cuando tu Tabla Users tenga un campo con valor IDENTITY.

Comment: He resuelto el problema, fue cuestión de ordenar la Query correctamente, mis disculpas